# PHP post iframe as image

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was wondering if there was a way to submit/post the content of an iframe to the next page as an image and display it as an image. Ideally without having to save the canvas in the iframe on the server some where

Comment: like getting text inputs and create an image through GD? maybe, you could try that one, anyway, its too broad, you'll need to be more specific, you could add an illustration at least

Comment: not sure what GD is? but the <iframe> tag is hosting a page that has a <canvas> dynamically generating graphs

Comment: Image.intervention and wkhtmltopdf, GD are pho image manipulation tools. You'd point one of those at the iframe and save a file from it to your environment and pass the image path to the view you want to see it on. Many ways to do this, I'd suggest some r&d before proceeding